# hardhat-deploy deploy proxy - Error: The number of arguments passed to not match the number of argument in the implementation constructor

Tags: hardhat-deploy, proxy-contracts

I have the following upgradeable contract using @import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

```
contract StargateSwap is Initializable, AccessControlUpgradeable, PausableUpgradeable {
using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    
bytes32 public constant OPERATOR_ROLE = keccak256("OPERATOR_ROLE");
uint16 public constant ETH_POOL_ID = 13;

address public stargateRouter;
address public stargateEthVault;
uint16 public dstPoolId;

mapping (address => bool) public validOutputTokens;

function initialize(
    address _stargateRouter, 
    address _stargateEthVault, 
    uint16 _destPoolId, 
    address[] memory _validOutputTokens
) public initializer {
    __Context_init_unchained();
    __AccessControl_init_unchained();
    _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _msgSender());
    _setupRole(OPERATOR_ROLE, _msgSender());
    stargateRouter = _stargateRouter;
    stargateEthVault = _stargateEthVault;
    dstPoolId = _destPoolId;
    for(uint i; i < _validOutputTokens.length; i++) {
        validOutputTokens[_validOutputTokens[i]] = true;
    }
}
```

And I am using the following deployment script using hardhat-deploy (https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat-deploy)

```
const STARGATE = require("../constants/stargate.json")

module.exports = async function ({ deployments, getNamedAccounts }) {
    const { deploy } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

    const stargateRouter = STARGATE.router[hre.network.name];
    const stargateEthVault = STARGATE.ethVault[hre.network.name];
    console.log(`[${hre.network.name}] Stargate Router address: ${stargateRouter}`);
    console.log(`[${hre.network.name}] Stargate ETH vault address: ${stargateEthVault}`);
    console.log(`[${hre.network.name}] Deployer: ${deployer}`);
    
    await deploy("Fiat24StargateSwap", {
        from: deployer,
        log: true,
        proxy: {
            owner: deployer,
            proxyContract: 'OpenZeppelinTransparentProxy',
            methodName: 'init',
        },
        args: [ stargateRouter, 
                stargateEthVault, 
                1, 
                ["0xbE00f3db78688d9704BCb4e0a827aea3a9Cc0D62", 
                "0x2c5d06f591D0d8cd43Ac232c2B654475a142c7DA", 
                "0xd41F1f0cf89fD239ca4c1F8E8ADA46345c86b0a4", 
                "0x5fc17218196581864974574d715cFC7334794cBE"]],
        waitConfirmations: 1,
    })
}
```

And I get the following error message:

`Error: The number of arguments passed to not match the number of argument in the implementation constructor. Please specify the correct number of arguments as part of the deploy options: "args"`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your function names don't match. Your script claims it's `init` but your contract has function `initialize`. Fix that.

Read more info about hardhat-deploy proxy deployment [here](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy#deploying-and-upgrading-proxies).

Comment: Thank you very much @Lauri Peltonen. I've changed to initialize, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The `args` option expects the constructor to have the specified arguments. When you need to pass arguments only to a proxy init function then you can do it like this instead:

```typescript
const deployed = await deploy("YourContract", {
  from: deployer,
  proxy: {
    execute: {
      init: {
        methodName: "initialize",
        args: ["arg1", "arg2"],
      },
    },
    proxyContract: "OpenZeppelinTransparentProxy",
  },
  log: true,
  autoMine: true,
});
```

Note that the we use `execute` instead and don’t specify any `args` for the constructor itself